# Conditions for augmenting a collection of sets so that the new sets are small but the hull is large?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, order-theory

This is the second of three self-answered questions which will culminate in a
proof of necessary and sufficient conditions for Krein-Milman type conclusions.

The first question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771345/are-there-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-so-that-every-element-in-a-partial).

The third question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771675/are-there-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-krein-milman-type-conclusions).

Suppose that $\mathfrak{P} = \langle P, \leq, \bot \rangle$ is a partially
ordered set.
Let $\mathbf{B}$ be the collection of all nonempty bounded subsets of $P$.
That is to say, if $B \in \mathbf{B}$ then there exists a $p \in P$ satisfying
$b \leq p$ for all $b \in B$.
Let $\mathsf{con} \colon \mathbf{B} \rightarrow P$ satisfy the following
conditions:

1. **Increasing Condition.** For all $B \in \mathbf{B}$ the element $\mathsf{con}(B)$ is an upper bound for $B$.
2. **Order Condition.** For all $B_{0}, B_{1} \in \mathbf{B}$; if for all $b_{0} \in B_{0}$ there exists a $b_{1} \in B_{1}$ with $b_{0} \leq b_{1}$ then $\mathsf{con}(B_{0}) \leq \mathsf{con}(B)$.
3. **Idempotence Condition.** For all $B \in \mathbf{B}$ we have $\mathsf{con}(\mathsf{con}(B)) = \mathsf{con}(B)$.
   Define $\mathbf{C} = \{ \mathsf{con}(B) \colon B \in \mathbf{B} \} $.
   Elements of $\mathbf{C}$ will be said to be *convex*.
   A *convex structure* will be denoted by $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq,
   \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$.

Suppose that $q\in P$ and the nonempty set $A \subseteq P \smallsetminus \{ \bot
\}$ has $q$ as an upper bound.
Are there necessary and sufficient conditions so that for all nonempty $E
\subseteq A$ if $q \nleq \mathsf{con}(E)$ then there exists an $E^{*} \subseteq
A$ satisfying (i) $E \subseteq E^{*}$, (ii) for all $e \in E$ and all $e^{*}
\in E^{*} \smallsetminus E$ we have $e \nleq e^{*}$, and (iii) $q \leq
\mathsf{con}(E^{*})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Definitions.**
In this collection of definitions we will suppose that $\mathfrak{P} = \langle P, \leq, \bot \rangle$ is a partially ordered set.
Recall that $\bot$ is the least element of $P$.

Suppose that $A_{0}, A_{1} \subseteq P$ are not empty.
Abusing notation, we will write
$A_{0} \leq A_{1}$
if and only if $a_{0} \leq a_{1}$ for all $a_{0} \in A_{0}$ and
all $a_{1} \in A_{1}$.
We will write $A_{0} \leq_{w} A_{1}$ if and only if for all $a_{0} \in A_{0}$ there exists an $a_{1} \in A_{1}$with $a_{0} \leq a_{1}$.

Suppose that $\mathsf{con} \colon
\mathbf{B} \rightarrow P$ satisfies the following conditions:

**Increasing Condition.** For $B \in \mathbf{B}$ we have $B \leq \mathsf{con}(B)$.

**Order Condition.** For $B_{0}, B_{1} \in \mathbf{B}$; if $B_{0} \leq_{w} B_{1}$ then we have $\mathsf{con}(B_{0})\leq \mathsf{con}(B_{1})$.

**Idempotence Condition.** For $B \in \mathbf{B}$ we have $\mathsf{con} \{ \mathsf{con}(B) \} = \mathsf{con}(B)$.
Then we will say that $\mathsf{con}$ is a *convex hull* operator for
$\mathfrak{P}$.
We will also say that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con}
\rangle$ is a *convex structure*.
Define
$$
  \mathbf{C} = \{ \mathsf{con}(B) \colon B \in \mathbf{B} \} \text{.}
$$
The elements of $\mathbf{C}$ will be called *convex* elements.
Since $\bot \leq_{w} B$ for any bounded $B$, the order condition implies that $\mathsf{con}(\{ \bot \} )$ is the smallest convex element.
We will denote this element by $\bot_{\mathsf{con}}$.
It may be the case that $\bot < \bot_{\mathsf{con}}$.

**2. Theorem.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure.
Then $\mathbf{C}$ is the underlying set for a complete lower semilattice whose order is induced by $\leq$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $C \subseteq \mathbf{C}$ is not empty.
Define
$$
  B = \{ b \in P \colon b \leq C \} \text{.}
$$
The set $B$ is bounded.
The  order and idempotence conditions implies that for all $c \in C$ we have
$$
  \mathsf{con}(B) \leq \mathsf{con}(\{ c \} ) = c \text{.}
$$
Thus $\mathsf{con}(B)$ is a lower bound in $\mathbf{C}$ for $C$.
Now suppose that $a \in \mathbf{C}$ is a lower bound for $C$.
Since $a \in P$ we see that $a \in B$.
The idempotence and order conditions imply that $a = \mathsf{con}(\{ a \}) \leq \mathsf{con} B$.
But then $\mathsf{con}(B)$ is the greatest lower bound, in $\mathbf{C}$, for $C$.

**3. Corollary.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure.
For all nonempty $C \subseteq \mathbf{C}$ and all $p \in P$; if $p = \wedge C$ then $p$ is convex.

**Proof.** Suppose that $C \subseteq \mathbf{C}$ is not empty and $p \in P$ is
the greatest lower bound for $C$ in $P$.
Using the notation from theorem 1 we see that $p \in B$. But then $p \leq 
\mathsf{con}( \{ p \} ) \leq \mathsf{con}( B ) \leq p$.

**4. Proposition.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure, we have $q \in P$, the set $\mathcal{A}$ is a nonempty collection of nonempty subsets of ${\downarrow} q$, and the function $f \colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow P$
satisfies: for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $A \leq f(A) \leq \mathsf{con}(A)$.
Then
$$
  \mathsf{con}(\cup \mathcal{A}) = \mathsf{con}(\{ f(A) \colon A \in
  \mathcal{A} \} ) = \mathsf{con}(\{ \mathsf{con}(A) \colon A \in
  \mathcal{A} \} ) \text{.}
$$

**Proof.** Using the order condition we have
      \begin{align}
 \cup \mathcal{A} &\leq_{w} \{ f(A) \colon A \in \mathcal{A} \} \leq_{w}
 \{ \mathsf{con}(A) \colon A \in \mathcal{A} \} \text{.} \\
 \mathsf{con}(\cup \mathcal{A}) &\leq \mathsf{con}(\{ f(A) \colon A \in
 \mathcal{A} \}) \leq \mathsf{con}(\{ \mathsf{con}(A) \colon A \in
 \mathcal{A} \}) \text{.}
      \end{align}
      For each $A \in \mathcal{A}$ we have $A \leq_{w} \cup \mathcal{A}$; hence
      $\mathsf{con}(A) \leq \mathsf{con}(\cup \mathcal{A})$.
      This means $\{ \mathsf{con}(A) \colon A \in \mathcal{A} \} \leq_{w} \{
      \mathsf{con}(\cup \mathcal{A}) \} $.
      The order and idempotent conditions imply
      $$
 \mathsf{con}(\{ \mathsf{con}(A) \colon A \in \mathcal{A} \} ) \leq
 \mathsf{con}(\cup \mathcal{A}) \text{.}
      $$

**5. Definitions.** Throughout this collection of definitions we will suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex
structure.

For all $E \in \mathbf{B}$ and all $p \in P$ satisfying $E \cup \{ p \} \in \mathbf{B}$ we will say that $p$ *augments* $E$ if and only if $e \nleq p$ for all $e \in E$ and $\mathsf{con}(E) < \mathsf{con}(E \cup \{ p \} )$.

Suppose that $q \in P$ and the set $A \subseteq {\downarrow} q$ is not empty.
We will say that $A$ satisfies the *augmentation* property if and only if for all nonempty $E \subseteq A$ if $q \nleq \mathsf{con}(E)$ then
there exists a $p \in A$ that augments $E$.
For all nonempty $E_{0}, E_{1} \subseteq A$ we will write
$$
  E_{0} \preceq E_{1}
$$
if and only if $E_{0} \subseteq E_{1}$ and, for all $e_{1} \in E_{1}
\smallsetminus E_{0}$, the element $e_{1}$ augments $E_{0}$.

**6. Lemma.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure.
Suppose also that $A_{0}, A_{1} \in \mathsf{B}$ and $p \in P$ satisfy:
 1. We have $A_{0} \subseteq A_{1}$.
 2. The set $A_{1}o \cup \{ p \} $ is bounded.
 3. We have $\mathsf{con}(A_{1}) < \mathsf{con}(A_{1} \cup \{ p \} )$.
Then $\mathsf{con}(A_{0}) < \mathsf{con}(A_{0} \cup \{ p \} )$.

**Proof.** The order condition implies $\mathsf{con}(A_{0}) \leq \mathsf{con}(A_{0} \cup \{ p \} )$.
For the purpose of deriving a contradiction suppose that $\mathsf{con}(A_{0}) = \mathsf{con}(A_{0} \cup \{ p \} )$.
Since
$$
  A_{1} \cup \{ p \} = A_{1} \cup (A_{0} \cup \{ p \} )
$$
proposition 4 and the properties of a convex hull operator imply
\begin{align}
   \mathsf{con}(A_{1} \cup \{ p \} )
     &= \mathsf{con}(A_{1} \cup (A_{0} \cup \{ p \} )) \\
     &= \mathsf{con}(\{ \mathsf{con}(A_{1}), \mathsf{con}(A_{0} \cup \{ p
     \} ) \} ) \\
     &= \mathsf{con}(\{ \mathsf{con}(A_{1}), \mathsf{con}(A_{0}) \} ) \\
     &= \mathsf{con}( \{ \mathsf{con}(A_{1}) \} ) \\
     &= \mathsf{con}(A_{1}) \text{.}
\end{align}
This is the desired contradiction.

**7. Lemma.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure.
The relation $\preceq$ is a partial order on $\mathbf{B}$.

**Proof.** Select $E \in \mathbf{B}$.
Since inclusion is reflexive and $E \smallsetminus E$ is empty the relation $\preceq$ is reflexive.
Since inclusion is anti-symmetric so is $\preceq$.
Select $E_{0}, E_{1}, E_{2} e\in \mathbf{B}$ and suppose we have both $E_{0}
\preceq E_{1}$ and $E_{1} \preceq E_{2}$.
If $E_{0} = E_{1}$ or $E_{1}= E_{2}$ then $E_{0} \preceq E_{2}$.
For the remainder of this proof we will suppose that neither $E_{1}
\smallsetminus E_{0}$ nor $E_{2} \smallsetminus E_{1}$ is empty.
Select $e_{2} \in E_{2}$.
If $e_{2} \in E_{1}$ then, since $E_{0} \preceq E_{1}$ the element $e_{2}$ augments $E_{0}$.
Suppose that $e_{2} \in E_{2} \smallsetminus E_{1}$.
Since $E_{0} \subseteq E_{1}$ and $E_{1} \preceq E_{2}$ we have
$\mathsf{con}(E_{1}) < \mathsf{con}(E_{1} \cup \{ e_{2} \} )$.
Recalling lemma 6 we see that $\mathsf{con}(E_{0}) < \mathsf{con}(E_{0} \cup \{ p \} )$.
But then $E_{0} \preceq E_{2}$.

**8. Theorem.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure.
Suppose also that $q \in P$ and $A \subseteq {\downarrow} q$ is not empty.
Then $A$ satisfies the augmentation property if and only if for all nonempty $E \subseteq A$ there exists an $E^{*} \subseteq A$ satisfying both $E \preceq E^{*}$ and $q \leq \mathsf{con}(E^{*})$.

**Proof.** In this paragraph we will suppose that $A$ satisfies the augmentation
property.
Choose a nonempty $E \subseteq A$.
Define
$$
  \mathcal{G} = \{ G \subseteq A \colon E \preceq G \} \text{.}
$$
Since $E \in \mathcal{G}$ the set $\mathcal{G}$ is not empty.
The relation $\preceq$ partially orders $\mathcal{G}$.
Suppose that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ is not empty and is totally ordered by inclusion.
We have $E \subseteq \cup \mathcal{T}$.
Select $g \in \cup \mathcal{T}$.
For some $G \in \mathcal{T}$ we have $g \in G$.
Since $E\preceq G$ the element $g$ augments $E$.
But then $\cup \mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{G}$.
Applying Zorn's lemma we see that $\mathcal{G}$ has a maximal element $E^{*}$
For the purpose of deriving a contradiction suppose that $q \nleq
\mathsf{con}(E^{*})$.
Since $A$ satisfies the augmentation property there exists a $p \in A$ that augments $E^{*}$.
But then $E^{*} \prec E^{*} \cup \{ p \} $ which contradicts the maximality of $E^{*}$.

In this paragraph we will suppose that for all nonempty $E \subseteq A$ there exists an $E^{*} \subseteq A$ satisfying both $E \preceq E^{*}$ and $q \leq \mathsf{con}(E^{*})$.
Select a nonempty $E \subseteq A$.
If $q \leq \mathsf{con}(E)$ there is nothing to prove.
Suppose that $q \nleq \mathsf{con}(E)$.
Choose $E^{*} \subseteq A$ satisfying both $E \preceq E^{*}$ and $q \leq E^{*}$.
Now choose $e^{*} \in E^{*} \smallsetminus E$ and note that $e^{*}$ augments $E$.

**9. Proposition.**
Suppose that $\mathfrak{C} = \langle P, \leq, \bot, \mathsf{con} \rangle$ is a convex structure.
The relation $\preceq$ is a partial order on $\mathbf{B}$.

**Proof.** Inclusion is reflexive.
In the case that $E_{1} = E_{0}$ the meet and hull conditions are vacuous. 
But then $\preceq$ is reflexive.
Since inclusion is anti-symmetric so is $\preceq$.
Select $E_{0}, E_{1}, E_{2} \in \mathbf{B}$ and suppose that $E_{0}
\preceq E_{1}$ and $E_{1} \preceq E_{2}$.
If $E_{0} = E_{}$ or $E_{1} = E_{2}$ then $E_{0} \preceq E_{2}$.
For the remainder of the proof we will suppose that neither $E_{1}
\smallsetminus E_{0}$ nor $E_{2} \smallsetminus E_{1}$ is empty.
Select $e_{0} \in E_{0}$ and $e_{2} \in E_{2} \smallsetminus E_{0}$.
If $e_{2} \in E_{1}$ then, since $E_{0} \preceq E_{1}$, it is not the case that $e_{0} \leq e_{2}$.
If $e_{2} \in E_{2} \smallsetminus E_{1}$ then, since $e_{0} \in E_{1}$ and $E_{1} \preceq E_{2}$, it is not the case that $e_{0} \leq e_{2}$.Thus the meet condition holds.
Select $e_{2} \in E_{2}$.
Lemma 6 implies that $\mathsf{con}(E_{0}) < \mathsf{con}(E_{0} \cup \{ e_{2} \} )$. 
But then the hull condition holds.